# Java isAssignableFrom Confusion

Tags: java, methods, reflection

I'm working with Java's `isAssignableFrom` method to create a sort of dynamic method calling for events in my program. In short, I'm given an array of `Class<?>` and a `Method` object, and I must determine whether the method can be called using the given parameters.

For the most part, `isAssignableFrom` works, but I have run into one particular issue: autoboxing. For instance, suppose the method takes an `int` and the `Class<?>[]` contains `Integer.class`. Realistically, Java will allow such a call to occur, but `int.class.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)` returns false. Currently, I have solved this using a static helper method as follows:

```
public static boolean isAssignable(Class<?> a, Class<?> b) {
    if (a.isAssignableFrom(b))
        return true;
    Class<?> a1 = box(a);
    Class<?> b1 = box(b);
    if (a1.isAssignableFrom(b1))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Where `box(Class<T>)` is a method that returns the boxed form of the class (`Integer.class` for `int.class`, etc.) or the class itself if it is not primitive.

My question would be: Is there a better way? The method I'm using seems roundabout and somewhat messy. Does anyone have a cleaner, more straightforward approach?